# Licenses requirements for using Custom Connectors inside Power Apps and inside Power Automate

Tags: office-365, licensing, power-platform

We have the following case:-

1. We will create a custom connector which integrate with 3rd party api using api key.
2. The custom connector will be called from these areas:-

   2.1) Power Apps. Directly from Canvas Power Apps. this power app will be used by 20 users.

   2.2) Power Automate >> these flows will run by service account. as scheduled flow and as automated flow (when an item is added)

So now regarding the licensing required, what is the exact case?

1. The 20 users will need 20 Power Apps Premium license?
2. The Service account will need 1 Power Automate Premium license?

Is this correct?

Thanks